# HTML5 video: how to turn off subtitles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating an HTML5 video player, and want a button that turns subtitles on and off. To switch them off, I'm setting the default track's "mode" attribute to "hidden", but they're not disappearing in Chrome 66.

Here's the line of jQuery that should turn subtitles off (the player's id is "player"):

```
$"#player track").eq(0).attr("mode", "hidden");
```

The "mode" attribute changes to "hidden" in the DOM, but the subtitles are still visible. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: `$"#player track")` should throw an error if that's what you've got in your code. It should be `$("#player track")`. Good idea to check developers tools > console for errors.

Comment: @Adriani6  OP mentioned that they see the attribute changing in their DOM, I'd imagine that's just a typo in the question.

Comment: @TylerRoper Oops, totally missed the last line...

Comment: Well; you should iterate all tracks that are in the video and set each of them to hidden not just the first one.

Comment: I agree with @Adriani6 , although you could probably just do `$("#player track").attr("mode", "hidden");` to set *all track modes to hidden*, without the need for iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon my comment; what you should try is disable the subtitles on all tracks (in case you have more than one).
There might be an easier way using jQuery, however I have never worked with html5 player using jQuery hence my answer.

```
var video = document.querySelector('#player');

for (var i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) {
   video.textTracks[i].mode = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: That's indeed the way to go (even though there is actually no need to loop over all the textTracks if we know which one is active), but OP's problem was that they set the `mode` attribute of the `track` element. These elements don't have such an attribute and indeed the best way is to go to the video's TextTrackList. What ould have had an effect from the track element itself wold have ben to modify one of its real attributes (e.g `src`)  or to remove it from the DOM, but that's obviously not the correct way when we just want to toggle off a TextTrack (which is not the `<track>` element)

Answer (score 0):

$(".ccbutton").click(function(){

```
var video = document.querySelector('#video');

for (var i = 0; i < video.textTracks.length; i++) {
   if(video.textTracks[i].mode == 'hidden')
          video.textTracks[i].mode = 'showing';
   else
          video.textTracks[i].mode = 'hidden';
}
```

});

Comment: please explain your code

Comment: this code just show/hide the entire active subtitle whatever which one is selected from the tracks list